# Find the limit of $n\log(n)/(n+1)\log(n+1)$?

Tags: limits

Could someone please explain how to work out the limit of :

$$\frac{n\log(n)}{(n+1)\log(n+1)},\qquad\mbox{ as $n\to\infty$}.$$

Comment: The expression in your title and in your question are different. Which is it?  Also, please make it clear which terms are in the numerator and which are in the denominator.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = 1$ $\implies$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)} = 1$ $\implies$ $...$

Comment: You lost a $+1$ in the argument of the second logarithm compared to your title.  Also, please use parentheses to show that the second log is in the denominator (isn't it?)

Comment: Ah sorry, it should be how it is stated in the title, the denominator should read : (n+1)log(n+1). Sorry!

Comment: @Oleg567 That needs a bit more justification; after all, $\lim\frac{n}{n+1}=1\not\!\!\!\implies \lim\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=1$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes, indeed. I was too quick with (draft) comment.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I was trying to use the ration test to show the sum of 1/(nlogn) diverges but since the sum appears to equal 1 the ratio test is inconclusive. Can anyone suggest another way of showing that the sum of 1/(nlogn) from 2 to infinity diverges please?

Comment: @Sadie Try the integral test; $\int\frac1{x\log x}dx$ can be evaluated explicitly (hint: try substituting $u=\log x$) and that should be enough to give you your answer.

Answer (score 5):

$$\ln(n+1)=\ln n\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)=\ln n+\ln\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\ln n}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}=1\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{\ln n+\ln\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)}=$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+\dfrac{\ln\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)}{\ln n}}=\frac1{1+0}=1.$$

Comment: How do you say that $\dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}}{\ln n}) =0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: @learnmore: $~\dfrac1n\to0~$ and $~\ln1=0~$ and $~\dfrac1{\ln n}\to0~$ as $~n\to\infty.$

Comment: okay i got it ;thanks

Answer (score 3):

Turn to functions on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and apply L'Hospital $\left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right)$ twice, if you know about it (if not, somebody else will attempt an elementary proof for you):

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\ln x }{(x+1)\ln(x+1)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x +1 }{\ln(x+1) +1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1/x }{1/(x+1)} = 1$$